# Pressing backspace repeats prompt - inputimeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, timeout

I am creating a program that asks the user to enter a guess based on an input. I am using the inputimeout module to make the user answer before a certain time, otherwise, the guess will be automatically incorrect.

Here is a shortened example of my code:

```
import time
from inputimeout import inputimeout, TimeoutOccurred


# Variables defined here for example code.
first_letter = "a"
second_letter = "b"
do_timeout = True
timeout_time = 5.0


# Problem area
if do_timeout:
    try:
        guess = (
            inputimeout(
                prompt=f"What is the memo word for the letter pair, {first_letter}{second_letter}?\n",
                timeout=timeout_time,
            )
        )
    except TimeoutOccurred:
        guess = None
# Problem area
else:
    guess = (
        input(
            f"What is the memo word for the letter pair, {first_letter}{second_letter}?\n"
        )
    )
```

When I set: `do_timeout = False`, the program runs perfectly as expected.
However, when set to: `do_timeout = True`, the program runs as expected unless I press the "backspace" key. When I press the "backspace" key, it will repeat the prompt every time I press this key.

I have to assume that there is some issue with the inputimeout module that is causing this to happen. Is there a way to fix this, or is there something else wrong with my program that is causing it.

Comment: I think the problem is with your `shell` (or `console`), could you please give us the detail of where do you run this application?

Comment: Maybe you should find a different library. I was looking for the documentation, and the link to the homepage no longer works. The library hasn't been updated in 5 years.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo I am using VS Code. I just tried it with a different shell and it didn't have the issue, so it does seem to be a problem with VS Code.

Comment: @Barmar The trouble is, I've only been able to find one other module that can do a similar thing, but that module doesn't work with Windows.